# @EnableAspectJAutoProxy failing Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aspectj

I am writing Spring MVC application which is deployed on tomcat. I want to add Spring AOP or AspectJ logger. 
So, I wrote a AspectLogger class:

```
@Aspect
@Service
class AspectLogger {

@Autowired
private MyLogger logger;

@Around("aop3()")
public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    logger.debug("$$$$ AOP Something");
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.dummy.DefController.*(..))")
public void aop3() {
}
```

And added to configuration annotation @EnableAspectJAutoProxy:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("pl.mythesis.spring")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

Dependencies in pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And I obtained this exceptions:

```
    09-Jan-2016 17:17:48.970 SEVERE [http-apr-8080-exec-14] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultController' defined in file [C:\Users\Kasiek\S6IS\Praca Magisterska\MyThesisSite\SpringSite\target\SpringSite\WEB-INF\classes\pl\mythesis\spring\controller\DefaultController.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/OrderUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1583)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1460)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:906)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:344)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:614)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/annotation/OrderUtils
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectInstanceFactory.getOrder(BeanFactoryAspectInstanceFactory.java:112)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.LazySingletonAspectInstanceFactoryDecorator.getOrder(LazySingletonAspectInstanceFactoryDecorator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.getOrder(InstantiationModelAwarePointcutAdvisorImpl.java:159)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.getOrder(OrderComparator.java:71)
    at org.springframework.core.OrderComparator.compare(OrderComparator.java:58)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJPrecedenceComparator.compare(AspectJPrecedenceComparator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJPrecedenceComparator.compare(AspectJPrecedenceComparator.java:49)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator$PartiallyComparableAdvisorHolder.compareTo(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:132)
    at org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder$SortObject.addDirectedLinks(PartialOrder.java:71)
    at org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder.addNewPartialComparable(PartialOrder.java:93)
    at org.aspectj.util.PartialOrder.sort(PartialOrder.java:129)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.sortAdvisors(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:330)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.annotation.OrderUtils
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    ... 74 more
```

Without annotation `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` application is running properly, but I don't see "$$$$ AOP Something" in log.

Comment: you are missing `OrderUtils`. this one comes from spring-core, make sure you don't have anything in the pom.xml that causes it not to be included

Comment: I have spring-core artifact in 4.0.6 version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to upgrade your `spring-core` to the same version as `spring-aop`.

You are missing `OrderUtils`, see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/OrderUtils.html) in the api- this one is since 4.1, if you have 4.0.6, it won't be there.

Generally speaking, it's good to keep all your spring dependencies on the same version

Comment: I can't upgrade all spring dependencies to 4.1, because then my front end doesn't work well. I don't know why, but I don't want to waste time for solving it :) thanks for help, everything is already working

Comment: You definitely should use the same version for all Spring dependencies. If you can't upgrade all dependencies to 4.1.4, use 4.0.6.

Comment: Use maven enforcer plugin with the [require same versions](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireSameVersions.html) rule to enforce same version between specific artifacts.